# How to wait for multiple WaitHandle array in async way in C# with cancellation support?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, waithandle

C# has a recommended method to wait for single WaitHandle object in non-blocking way through `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. But I need something similar but for multiple objects. Something like `WaitHandle.WaitAll` but in async variant. How to achieve this in less resources wasteful way? Now I think about task creation and wait the handles there, something like this:

```
public static class WaitHandleExtension
{
    public static Task<bool> WaitAllAsync ( this WaitHandle[] handles )
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew( () => WaitHandle.WaitAll( handles ) );
    }
}
```

But I can't implement cancellation in such approach. What will be the best way to wait all handles async with cancellation support?

**UPD: Here I describe a task I'm solving, maybe someone will suggest a different way to implement it in async:**

I'm implementing cross-platform IPC stream that works like named pipe but in simplified manner. It should be fully async and support cancellation. It should support Mono on macOS and Windows, because server app relies on Mono and can't use .NET on Windows. The problem is: Mono on Windows doesn't support UNIX domain sockets at all and named pipes implementation is not complete (named pipe connection can't be canceled on Mono Windows). I implemented macOS part on UNIX domain sockets and it works great. On Windows I decided to implement my own Stream class based on Memory Mapped File. It has two shared read-write buffers for duplex data exchange. Each buffer protected by named Semaphore and has two named events EventWaitHandle, one signals that buffer is not empty and another that buffer is not full. So, Send method waits for semaphore and non-full event to fill the buffer with data and signal non-empty event, if the buffer is fulfilled it resets non-full event. Read waits for semaphore and non-empty event to consume data and signal non-full event, if it consumes all the data it resets non-empty event. It works perfectly in sync way. But it would be great to implement cancellable ReadAsync and WriteAsync.

Comment: Cancellation is not provided.  Not because it is hard to do, it is easy by looping with WaitAny, but because it is about impossible to do anything meaningful next.  You've got a bunch of threads in a highly unpredictable state.  That RWFSO is efficient is a bit misleading as well.  There is still a thread, you just can't see it in the debugger because it is an unmanaged thread.  It doesn't start paying off until you use it multiple times concurrently.

Comment: @HansPassant I got it. It seems it is impossible to implement async waiter in common case. I described a task I'm solving in details. So, maybe there is some async cancellable solution for this specific task?

Answer (score 0):

This works, but feels a bit dirty. The idea is to efficiently wait for any one handle to complete, including the cancel token's handle.  If one of the handles (other than the cancel token) completes, remove it from the list of remaining handles and efficiently wait again, until all the handles have completed OR the cancel token wait handle has completed.

```
static async Task<bool> WaitForHandlesAsync(WaitHandle[] handles, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    List<WaitHandle> remainingHandles = new List<WaitHandle>(handles.Length + 1);
    remainingHandles.Add(cancellationToken.WaitHandle);
    remainingHandles.AddRange(handles);
    bool canceled = cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested;
    while (remainingHandles.Count > 1 && !canceled) {
        int idx = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitHandle.WaitAny(remainingHandles.ToArray()));
        if (idx == 0)
            canceled = true;
        else {
            remainingHandles.RemoveAt(idx);
        }
    }
    return !canceled;
}
```

Comment: I got the idea. But the problem is that when we remove some handle from the list it can become non-signaled at the and of common waiting operation and common state of all handles will be inconsistent. I updated my question with the description of the task I'm solving, maybe you have an idea how to implement this particular task?

Comment: If the only thing wait handles you are waiting on are semaphores, then use `SemaphoreSlim`, which has `WaitAsync` that is cancelable.

Comment: I can't use SemaphoreSlim, because it can't be named and shared across processes. I need waiting for two objects Semaphore and EventWaitHandle, they should signal simultaneously without splitting wait into two different waits.